# Dagger 2 inject error in AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm newbie for Dagger.
Current I create sample project some snip code:

MyComponent.java

```
@PerActivity
@Component(modules = MyModule.class)
public interface MyComponent {
    void inject(TutorialActivity activity);
}
```

MyModule.java

```
@Module
public class MyModule {
    @Provides
    Position providePosition() {
        return new Position();
    }
}
```

PerActivity.java

```
@Scope
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface PerActivity {}
```

TutorialActivity.java

```
public class TutorialActivity extends AppCompatActivity{}
```

When compile project I get error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected one element but was: <android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity, android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder.SupportParentable>
```

So if I change TutorialActivity as:

```
public class TutorialActivity extends Activity{}

or even

public class TutorialActivity{} // Without extends
```

Then it will working normally.(I can see class generated by Dagger2).

Please help !

Thanks.

UPDATE

My project structure:

- `common` module.
- `app` module. (app module will use common module as depended in gradle).

In both build.gradle (common and app module) I added:

```
apt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${daggerVersion}"
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:${daggerVersion}"
```

In build.gradle at common module:

```
provide "org.glassfish:javax.annotation:${javaxAnnotationVersion}"
```

An error only occurs if I have 2 module. (module `app` depended on `common`).
If I move my Component/Module to module `common` -> It work.
But when I move that to `app` module -> Error when compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @plash for your answer.

After I re-check for both module. 
I found I only added:

```
provide "org.glassfish:javax.annotation:${javaxAnnotationVersion}"
```

in `common` module.

After I added that provide for both module then compile success.(Dagger generated class.)

Comment: @plast But I still don't know why: TutorialActivity extends Activity 
=> working; But extends from AppCompatActivity -> Error when compile

Comment: Yes, I import support library correct. `compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibararyVersion"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$supportLibararyVersion"`

Comment: I'm not sure what your issue is then.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that your issue is a problem with Dagger because I don't see you requesting any dependencies in your Android components.

Nonetheless you need this in your `build.gradle` to use the depdendency injection annotations.

```
 provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

Comment: @plash in my project I added javax.annotation.

Comment: @plash see my answer. I found problem is should be added provided javax.annotation for both module.